# Анимация прозрачности

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval

Друзья, помогите пожалуйста. Надо, чтобы звезды мерцали - то есть рандомное значение opacity [0; 1), дойдя до 0.9, "гасло", а дойдя до 0.1 - снова росло.

```js
const SF_SIZE = 1; 
const SF_COUNT = 1000;
const WIND = 0.7;
const SPEED = 1.2;

var r = 255;
var g = 255;
var b = 0;

var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"), 
    sfArr = []; 

context.lineWidth = SF_SIZE;  

for(let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
  sfArr.push({
    x: randomInt(-canvas.width * WIND, canvas.width - 1),
    y: randomInt(0, canvas.height - 1),
    op: Math.random()
  });
}

let intrvl = setInterval(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
   if (sfArr[i].op < 0.1) {
      sfArr[i].op += 0.1;   
    }
  
 else if (sfArr[i].op>0.9)
 { sfArr[i].op -= 0.1;} 
 
  context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ', ' + sfArr[i].op + ')';
  snowflake(sfArr[i].x, sfArr[i].y, sfArr[i].op);  
  }
}, 200);

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function snowflake(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y){
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y);
context.lineTo(squarePosition_x + context.lineWidth, squarePosition_y + context.lineWidth);
context.stroke(); 
}
```

```css
#drawingCanvas {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: #000; 
 }
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect -->

<canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
```

Вот в этом условии что-то не так. Заранее спасибо

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/04pe3362/12/

Comment: А что происходит, когда `sfArr[o].op >= 0.1 && <= 0.9`?

Comment: @Darth да, математически неверно составила. Переделала под вот этоsfArr[i].op += 0.1;     
 if (sfArr[i].op >= 0.9)
 {sfArr[i].op -= 0.1;} Но все равное "гашения" не происходит https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/04pe3362/14/

Answer (score 4):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```js
const SF_SIZE = 1; 
const SF_COUNT = 1000;
const WIND = 0.7;
const SPEED = 1.2;

var r = 255;
var g = 255;
var b = 0;

var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"), 
    sfArr = []; 

context.lineWidth = SF_SIZE;  

for(let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
  sfArr.push({
    x: randomInt(-canvas.width * WIND, canvas.width - 1),
    y: randomInt(0, canvas.height - 1),
    op: Math.random(),
// Для каждой звезды по отдельности храним, тухнет она в данный момент или разгорается. Можно вынести этот флаг для всех звёзд оптом
    delta_opacity: 0.1 
  });
}

let intrvl = setInterval(() => {

  // Если не очищать - то старые звездочки так и останутся отрисованными
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // И ничего мерцать не будет

  for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
    if (sfArr[i].op < 0.1 || sfArr[i].op > 0.9) {
      sfArr[i].delta_opacity = -sfArr[i].delta_opacity;   
    }
    sfArr[i].op += sfArr[i].delta_opacity;   
 
  context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ', ' + sfArr[i].op + ')';
  snowflake(sfArr[i].x, sfArr[i].y, sfArr[i].op);  
  }
}, 200);

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function snowflake(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y){
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(squarePosition_x, squarePosition_y);
context.lineTo(squarePosition_x + context.lineWidth, squarePosition_y + context.lineWidth);
context.stroke(); 
}
```

```css
#drawingCanvas {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: #000; 
 }
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect -->

<canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: лучшее спасибо - отметьте ответом, поставьте плюс