# Фукция задержки для каждого элементам массива

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Друзья, в англоязычном **SO** нашла [очень хорошую функцию](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/8qe7422x/), устанавливающую задержку для каждого элемента массива.

Хотелось бы научиться ее практически применять.
Не срабатывает, надо, чтобы каждый из квадратов становился непрозрачным (`opacity` менялась от `0` до `1`) по очереди.

Что тут не так? Возможно, надо `opacity` сделать входным параметром. Попыталась, но неправильно. Заранее спасибо.

```
function ArrayPlusDelay1(array, delegate, delay) {
    array.forEach(function (el, i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
           delegate(array[i]);      
        }, i * delay);
    });
}
var int = ArrayPlusDelay1(sfArr, appearance, 1000);
```

```js
const SF_SIZE = 1;
const SF_COUNT = 4;

var r = 255;
var g = 255;
var b = 255;
var a = 0;
var nom = 0;

var pos_x = 0;
var pos_y = 0;

var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  sfArr = [];
context.lineWidth = SF_SIZE;
var halfX = canvas.width / 16;
var halfY = canvas.height / 16;

for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
  sfArr.push({
    x: 10 * i,
    y: 10 * i,
  });
}

function changeSnow() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
    snowflake(sfArr[i].x, sfArr[i].y);
  }
}

function snowflake(pos_x, pos_y) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(halfX - (pos_x - nom) / 2 + 100, halfY - (pos_y - nom) / 2 + 50, halfX + pos_x - nom, halfY + pos_y - nom + 10);
  context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')';
  context.stroke();
}

function appearance() {
  a += 0.1;
  setTimeout("appearance()", 1000);
  changeSnow();
}

function ArrayPlusDelay1(array, delegate, delay) {
  array.forEach(function(el, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      delegate(array[i]);
    }, i * delay);
  })
}

var int = ArrayPlusDelay1(sfArr, appearance, 1000);

window.onload = function() {
  changeSnow();
}
```

```css
#drawingCanvas {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите, чтоб квадраты становились непрозрачными по очереди, а переменная, где лежит альфа-канал, у вас одна на всех.
Вам нужно хранить прозрачность каждого квадрата отдельно.
[Тут у вас была почти такая же проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782621/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/782647#782647)

```js
const SF_SIZE = 1;
const SF_COUNT = 11;

var r = 255;
var g = 255;
var b = 255;
var nom = 0;

var pos_x = 0;
var pos_y = 0;

var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas"),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  sfArr = [];
context.lineWidth = SF_SIZE;
var halfX = canvas.width / 16;
var halfY = canvas.height / 16;

for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
  sfArr.push({
    x: 10 * i,
    y: 10 * i,
    // альфа канал квадрата
    a: 0
  });
}

function changeSnow() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < SF_COUNT; i++) {
    snowflake(sfArr[i].x, sfArr[i].y, sfArr[i].a);
  }
}

function snowflake(pos_x, pos_y, a) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(halfX - (pos_x - nom) / 2 + 100, halfY - (pos_y - nom) / 2 + 50, halfX + pos_x - nom, halfY + pos_y - nom + 10);
  context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a + ')';
  context.stroke();
}

// В этой переменной лежит индекс текущего квадрата
var quad_number = 0;
function appearance() {
  if(quad_number < sfArr.length){
      sfArr[quad_number].a += 0.1;
      // Если квадрат уже полностью непрозрачный - беремся за следующий
      if(sfArr[quad_number].a >= 1) {
         quad_number++;
      }  
      setTimeout("appearance()", 666);
      changeSnow();  
  }
  // else квадраты кончились
}

function ArrayPlusDelay1(array, delegate, delay) {
  array.forEach(function(el, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      delegate(array[i]);
    }, i * delay);
  })
}

var int = ArrayPlusDelay1(sfArr, appearance, 1000);

window.onload = function() {
  changeSnow();
}
```

```css
#drawingCanvas {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я так и поняла, что a должно быть входящим параметром, но не получилось это технически оформить. В той ветке было рандомное, а тут заданное.